# Prove that $q^i \equiv 1 \pmod {n!}$ for all $q, n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ where the prime factors of $q$ are greater than $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factorial

The question originally states:

> Let $n$ and $q$ are positive integers, such that all prime divisors of $q$ are greater than $n$. Show that $$(q-1)(q^2-1)(q^3-1)...(q^{n-1}-1) \equiv 0 \pmod {n!}$$

I decided it would be easier to attempt and prove that there will always be at least one $q^i \equiv 1 \pmod {n!}$ but failed. I was hoping to get some assistance (maybe a hint) on this question since I never dealt with factorial and a modular question.

Comment: Note: $q$ having all prime divisors greater than $n$, is the same as to say that $q$ and $n!$ are co-prime.

Comment: @Jakobian I already tried using the fact that they are coprime but failed.

Answer (score 1):

For each prime natural number $p\leq n$, the largest nonnegative integer $r$ such that $p^r$ divides $n!$ is $r=e_p(n)$, where
$$e_p(n):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor\,.$$
We shall prove that if $E_{p,q}(n)$ is the largest nonnegative integer $r$ such that $p^r$ divides $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\,\left(q^k-1\right)$, then
$$e_p(n)\leq E_{p,q}(n)\,.$$

Let $v_p$ be the [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) (that is, $e_p(n)=v_p(n!)$ and $E_{p,q}(n)=v_p\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\,\left(q^{k}-1\right)\right)$).  We have for every positive integer $k$ that
$$v_p\left(q^{k(p-1)}-1\right)=v_p\left(q^{p-1}-1\right)+v_p(k)\geq 1+v_p(k)$$
by the [Lifting-the-Exponent Lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/).  (The inequality $v_p\left(q^{p-1}-1\right)\geq 1$ is due to [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).)

In particular, we see that
$$E_{p,q}(n)\geq \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{p-1}\right\rfloor}\,v_p\left(q^{k(p-1)}-1\right)\geq \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{p-1}\right\rfloor}\,\left(1+v_p(k)\right)\,.$$
Since $e_p(n)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor}\,v_p(pk)= \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor}\,\left(1+v_p(k)\right)$ and $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n-1}{p-1}\right\rfloor \geq \left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p}\right\rfloor$, we conclude that
$$E_{p,q}(n)\geq \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor}\,\left(1+v_p(k)\right)=e_p(n)\,.$$

---

It is however not true that $q^i\equiv 1\pmod{n!}$ for some $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  For example, take $n:=6$ and $q:=11$.  Then,
$$q^1-1=10\not\equiv0\pmod{6!}\,,$$
$$q^2-1=120\not\equiv0\pmod{6!}\,,$$
$$q^3-1=1330\equiv 610\equiv\not\equiv0\pmod{6!}\,,$$
$$q^4-1=14640\equiv 240\not\equiv0\pmod{6!}\,,$$
$$q^5-1=161050\equiv 490 \not\equiv0\pmod{6!}\,.$$
and
$$q^6-1=1 1771560\equiv 360\not\equiv 0\pmod{6!}\,.$$

Comment: What I was trying to say is that there will always exist $q^i$ where $q^i \equiv 1 \pmod {n!}$

Comment: If you mean there will always exist an integer $q$ such that $q^i\equiv 1\pmod{n!}$, then it is a true statement since $q=1$ works.  If you say, for any $q$ such that $\gcd(q,n!)=1$, there will always exist a positive integer $i$ such that $q^i\equiv1 \pmod{n!}$, then this is also true by picking  $i=\phi(n!)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.  ***However***, if you say, for any $q$ such that $\gcd(q,n!)=1$, there will always exist a positive integer $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $q^i\equiv1 \pmod{n!}$, then the second part of my answer illustrates that this is false.

Comment: I understand now why my step was false, but now is there a different step I can possibly take.